# Valid username characters using SQL provider for ASP.NET membership

Tags: asp.net-membership

What are the valid characters for a user name when using the SQL provider for ASP.NET membership?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's any character except for commas (,). The only other restriction is your database encoding settings.

You can view the source for the `SqlMembershipProvider.CreateUser` method, and the `aspnet_Membership_CreateUser` stored procedure in the database to verify.

Edit, further evidence:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.updateuser.aspx

> [An exception is thrown if] the
>   UserName  property of user is an empty
>   string (""), contains a comma, or is
>   longer than 256 characters.